# Sign flag does not change value to "1" assembly

Tags: assembly, x86-16, flags, emu8086

I have a question regarding the sign flag, as I get it the sign flag should switch to 1 when the MSB is "1"
Why in the following example sign flag set to zero after the `sub` operation.

```
 mov cx, 720h
 sub cl,0f6h
```

I understand that the operation occurs here is cl=20h and then 20h-f6h, as I understand it should be negative please explain.

Comment: 20h &minus; f6h is 2ah which does not have its most significant bit set, so SF is cleared.

Comment: Can you provide me the steps you have done? if I am using a calculator I am getting FFFF2A, since its only cl I should take the most 2 right letters/digits and then convert it to binary and look if the MSB in 8 bits set to 1?

Comment: Yes, CL is an 8-bit register.  Look at it in a debugger.  The 8-bit subtraction has unsigned wraparound (CF set), but not signed overflow (so OF is clear), and positive - negative  without overflow is positive.  http://teaching.idallen.com/dat2343/10f/notes/040_overflow.txt

Comment: @AmitayTsinis Your reasoning is correct.  `cl` is an 8 bit register, so it only stores 2ah.

Comment: It'd be "0x20 - 0xF6 = (+32) - (-10) = (+42)". Note that it'd be nice if the assembler could give you warning (e.g. "value 0xF6 is too large for signed 8-bit integer"); but this is not possible because the assembler can't know that it's a signed integer and has to assume that it may be an unsigned integer (and therefore has to assume that there's no problem because 0xF6 does fit in an 8-bit unsigned integer).